# How can I set the value of a dropdown that is populated dynamically?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails to render a form.

It has a drop-down list that is populated from the controller.

```
<div class="formField">
    <span class="formlabel"> Status</span>
    <div id="shipment_options">
        <%= select_tag "filters[status]", options_for_select(@outgoing_shipment_status),:prompt => "All", :id => "shipment_status_id" %></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`@outgoing_shipment_status` is populated in the controller say (A,B,C,D,E).

I want to pre-set the value of the drop-down to a particular value from the list say (B) which I pass as a hash parameter in the URL.
This is what I am trying,

localhost:36080/form_page#B

```
var status = window.location.hash.substr(1); //checked the value of status is "B"
$("#shipment_status_id").val(status);
```

Also tried

localhost:36080/form_page?status=B

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var status = urlParams.get('status');
console.log(status); //correct value "B"
$("#shipment_status_id").val(status);
```

But it throws an Internal Server Error. It seems like it tries to call the form method due to the '#' and fails in the first case and doesn't do anything in the second.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this better?

Comment: Does

$('#shipment_status_id option[value='+status+']').attr('selected','selected'); works ?

Comment: @DylanKas No it doesn't

Comment: I do not know Ruby on rails, but does your <%= select_tag create a html <select> ?

Comment: @DylanKas yes it creates a SELECT tag, I've edited the question with some additional too.

Comment: Can you please share the URL with hash parameter ?

Comment: Dose changing your code to $("#shipment_status_id").val("B"); works ? or is it really an issue with status ?

Comment: @code_aks I have edited the question with the urls

Comment: @Dylas Kas no, that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this :-

```
## syntax
select_tag "credit_card", options_for_select([ "VISA", "MasterCard" ], "MasterCard")
```

According to your code :-

```
<%= select_tag "filters[status]", options_for_select(@outgoing_shipment_status, params[:status]),:prompt => "All", :id => "shipment_status_id" %>
```

For more check this reference :-
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag